# Why does Python return a complex number for operation x**x if -1 < x < 0?

Tags: python, complex-numbers

I am on Windows 10 (64-Bit machine with 32-Bit Python 3.7).
In IDLE, if I type:

```
>>> -0.001**-0.001
-1.0069316688518042
```

But if I do:

```
>>> x = -0.001
>>> x**x
(1.006926699847276 -0.0031633639300006526j)
```

Interestingly, **the magnitude of this complex number is the same as the actual answer.**

As a proof, I've attached screenshot of the same.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first case, you are not getting a complex number because `**` has higher precedence than `-` (both in Python and in math), so you are actually doing `-(0.001 ** -0.001)`. Try `(-0.001) ** -0.001`.

The complex number is the "correct" answer by the mathematical definition of the power operation.

Answer (score 1):

in Python, operator `**` means `to the power of`, a negative number taking a negative power shall create an imaginary number, as just like `sqrt(-1)=i`.

if you meant for multiplication, you should use `x*x` instead of `x**x`